# Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attempts' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a simple guessing game for my class with graphics and I'm trying to make an attempt counter. This is the area where my code is going wrong.

```
def value():

    guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
    if guess > num:
        attempts = attempts + 1
        turtle.clearscreen()
        interface()
        tooHigh()
        attempt = turtle.Turtle()
        attempt.speed(0)
        attempt.color("white")
        attempt.penup()
        attempt.hideturtle()
        attempt.goto(-250 , 200)
        attempt.write(guess, font=("Courier", 14, "bold"))
        value()
    elif guess < num:
        attempts = attempts + 1
        turtle.clearscreen()
        interface()
        tooLow()
        attempt = turtle.Turtle()
        attempt.speed(0)
        attempt.color("white")
        attempt.penup()
        attempt.hideturtle()
        attempt.goto(-250 , 200)
        attempt.write(guess, font=("Courier", 14, "bold"))
        value()
    elif guess == num:
        attempts = attempts + 1
        turtle.clearscreen()
        interface()
        yes()
        attempt = turtle.Turtle()
        attempt.speed(0)
        attempt.color("pink")
        attempt.penup()
        attempt.hideturtle()
        attempt.goto(-250 , 200)
        attempt.write(guess, font=("Courier", 14, "bold", "underline"))
        print ("Correct!")
    else:
        print ("ERROR")

def startScreen():

    begin = input("Start the game?: ")
    if begin == 'yes':
        value()
    elif begin == 'instructions':
        instructions()
        startScreen()
    elif begin == 'no':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print ("Unrecognised answer.")
        startScreen()

attempts = 0    
num = random.randint(1,1000)  
interface()   
startScreen()
```

The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\Python Programs\Game.py", line 154, in <module>        
    `startScreen()`        
  File "D:\Desktop\Python Programs\Game.py", line 141, in startScreen        
    `value()`        
  File "D:\Desktop\Python Programs\Game.py", line 110, in value        
    `attempts = attempts + 1`        
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attempts' referenced before assignment
```

It doesn't seem possible to move `attempts` into the function as it constantly calls itself, resetting `attempts` each time.

I am unsure why this is occurring so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As you assign something to `attempts` somewhere in your function, Python will by default consider it local. But the first time you use it, when trying to calculate `attempts + 1`, it hasn't been given a value, hence the error. If you mean to use the global `attempts`, you have to make it explicit. Add at the beginning of your function `global attempts`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to keep track of `attempts` outside of the function? if not, just move `attempts = 0` to the start of the function to initialize the local variable in the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because of something called `variable scope`. You have defined the variable `attempts` outside of the function `value`, so the function will not recognize any *local* variable by the name `attempts` unless you explicitly put the statement `global attempts` at the beginning of your function. This will tell the function that you want to use the variable `attempts` that you defined in your main program. That should look like this:

```
def value():
       global attempts
       #function code
```

Alternatively, you can allow your function `value` to take an argument, and pass the variable `attempts` into that. That would look something like this:

```
def value(attempts):
       #function code
       #you can use the variable attempts as needed, since you're passing it directly into the function

#call the function however you want
attempts = 0
value(attempts)
```

Comment: Ahh. I assumed you had to define the variable immediately underneath the `global`. Changed the code and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the function, when you access a variable for assignment, it by-default is treated as a local variable. So, to make Python know that the variable that you want to modify is a global variable, you do the following:

```py
def value():
    global attempts
    
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: I thought of this however the function call itself later in the code meaning if I define `attempts` in the function it constantly resets itself.

Comment: Right. I missed the part where you call the `value()` within itself. That would indeed reset the counter. So, ya, it should be outside. I will update the answer.